# Meaning of U suffix

Tags: c++, c

What does the postfix (or suffix) `U` mean for the following values?

```
0U
100U
```

Comment: Note that where you see U, it's common to use the lowercase version "u", because when it's capitalized it can be easily be confused with hex constants. I.e. 0xFFFFFFFFu is more obvious than 0xFFFFFFFFU.

Comment: the title says all, so why i need to write the question body?

Comment: @BillyONeal `0x11111110ll`

Comment: @Sugar: I guess I use F a lot more than 0 and 1 in hex constants :)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It stands for `unsigned`.

When you declare a constant, you can also specify its type. Another common example is `L`, which stands for `long`. (and you have to put it twice to specify a 64-bit constant).

Example: `1ULL`.

It helps in avoiding explicit casts.

Comment: There are also cases where it's necessary. For instance, integral constants are interpreted as integers by the compiler, so a constant like `0xffffffffffffffff` will lose its high 32 bits without the `ll` suffix.

Comment: @zneak actually, it won't. Integral literals have the type that can hold the value (if such a type exists). See [The type of the literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal). Thus, the type of your example literal is `long unsigned int` on GCC 8.4.0 x86_64.

Answer (score 52):

Integer constants in C and C++ can optionally have several suffixes:

- `123u` - the value 123 is an unsigned int
- `123l` - (that's a lowercase L) 123 is a signed long
- `123L` - ditto
- `123uL` - unsigned long
- `123LL` - a signed long long, a 64 bit or 128 bit value (depending on the environment)
- `123uLL` - unsigned long long

You can read more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) says for "12345...u" that "the type is unsigned long long even without a long long suffix". Quite confusing, since your answer says 123u is unsigned int. Who is right, or where is the misunderstanding?

Comment: @Ela782:  I looked at cpp reference, but couldn't find anything which says "u" implies long long.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: If you click my link in the comment above, near the bottom of that page, as a comment in the code example, it says: `<< 12345678901234567890u   << '\n'; // the type is unsigned long long even without a long long suffix`. Did you find that?
It's certainly possible that I misunderstand that sentence.

Comment: @Ela782:  Oh, I see.  That comment presumes it is compiled for a machine which *has* `long long` and since the constant exceeds the range for `long` it is already a `long long`.

Comment: Ooh I get it now, I see! Thank you! You mean "since it exceeds the range for (unsigned) `int`" though, because `u` would make it an (unsigned) `int` - but because the number is so large, it'll make an (unsigned) `long long`. Correct?

Comment: @Ela782:  Yep.  I am not sure off the top of my head, but without the `u` it could well be a signed long long.  (checked) Nope, it overflows a 64-bit signed int.  The `u` is needed.   If the architecture it were compiled for had 128-bit `int`s one could choose either signed or unsigned.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you very much for this explanation! Makes it very clear now :-)