# Trailing u in Hex Number C/C++

Tags: c++, c, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of U suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380691/meaning-of-u-suffix)

I'm going through code that has a bunch of defines that look like:
    #define HEX_NUMBER (0x000000FFu)

What is the trailing u?  I've tried compiling with and without it and I don't see any difference.

Comment: Thought the same, but case is different so I didn't follow thru.  lower case is different enough for me in case sensitive C/C++ land.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, the linked question has a relevant comment about the casing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Appending `u` to any integral constant makes the compiler interpret it as unsigned.

Comment: "interpret" is a bit misleading. What's happening is that the *type* of the literal expression is an unsigned type.