# Why are constants terminated by use of L or UL etc

Tags: c, constants

Why are constants in C terminated by use of L or UL etc. For example 
`unsigned long x = 12345678UL;`

My question is what is the significance of this and are there any advantages in doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of U suffix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380691/meaning-of-u-suffix)

Comment: @AlanB I saw the question which is commented. But my question is different. I want to know the reason behind doing this.

Answer (score 4):

because any number such as `12345` is treated as an integer in C. The problem comes when you try to do bitwise operations on them. Then, it can overflow.
This can have serious untracable errors and bugs. To avoid that, when a larger constant number is to  be assigned to a `(unsigned)long` variable, `UL` and `L` are used.

`UL` is to tell the compiler to treat the integer token as an `unsigned long` rather than `int`

`L` is to tell the compiler to treat the integer token as `long` rather than `int`.

Comment: an overflowing number don't have to become a negative number. for example `18253611008` will become `1073741824` for `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: integer constants never overflow, but get promoted to a larger type that can represent the value

Answer (score 2):

The suffix of an integer constant forces a *minimum* integer type, but the compiler will choose a large one (consistent with some constraints on signedness) if the number cannot be represented in it (see C11 6.4.4.1, in particular the table after §5).

If all you do is use the constant to initialize a variable, you don't need any suffix (except for the edge case of a number that is in range of `unsigned long long`, but not `long long` - in that case, any of the unsigned suffixes `u`, `ul` or `ull` as well as octal or hexadecimal representation can be used - decimal integer constants without suffix only promote to signed types).

Suffixes become important if you use the constants in more complex expressions because they will determine the result of it, eg

```
32u << 30
```

has type `unsigned` and will truncate the value, whereas

```
32ull << 30
```

won't.

Answer (score 1):

*I saw the question which is commented. But my question is different. I want to know the reason behind doing this.*

The reason is overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long a = 1U << 32;  // (1U  = unsigned int)
    unsigned long b = 1UL << 32; // (1UL = unsigned long int)

    printf("%lu %lu\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

On my computer `int` is 32 bits and `long` is 64, this is the output:

```
0 4294967296
```

This is what happens:

```
a 000000000000000000000000000000000000001 1U
 ^--------------------------------------- << 32 left shift count >= width of type
b 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 1UL
                                        ^---------------------------------- << 32
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that C is very badly designed, and will forcibly convert numbers that are too large into an `int` for no reason whatsoever, unless the programmer hasn't explicitly told the compiler not to be incredibly stupid via. various "numerical constant suffixes" (like `UL`).

Note that these "numerical constant suffixes" only really push the problem to larger numbers while also causing additional portability problems. For a simple example, consider `uint64_t myNumber = 0xFDECBA9876543210UL;` (which will break when compiled on a compiler where `long int` is only 32-bits).

For another example; consider `uint128_t myNumber = 0xFDECBA9876543210FDECBA9876543210ULL;` which is broken on virtually all compilers (where `long long` is 64-bit or smaller), and there is no way to do it correctly (as there simply isn't any "128-bit suffix" that can be used).

Comment: integer constants use the first type that can represent the number, with a minimum size given by the suffix; if there is an extended unsigned integer type that can represent your number, it will be used, whether or not the `u`, `ul` or `ull` suffix is used

Comment: @Christoph: This depends on which version of C. The original (K&R) C had no `u` suffix and would only promote to `long` (and never `unsigned long`). ANSI C increased this to `unsigned long`; but you're still screwed for both examples I gave. I don't know about (or care about) later versions of C.

Comment: you only care for ANSI C, but make your argument using `stdint.h` fixed-width types and `long long`?