# How do I solve 10.4 MISRA 2012 rule?

Tags: c, misra

Essential type of the left hand operand `usart[0U].tx_count` (unsigned) is not the same as that of the right operand "0" (signed).

```
if(usart[RS485_PORT].tx_count == 0) // error in this line
```

Comment: what's the type of the variables and fields? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Hi,

Your solution works,  can you tell me why it works?

Thank you!

Comment: The tool literally tells you what the problem is. As does the MISRA-C document. You cannot use MISRA-C without first studying MISRA-C. If you blindly trust some tool, you are in for disaster.

Answer (score 4):

`0` is a literal of type `int` which is a `signed` type, and `tx_count` is an `unsigned` field. Comparison between signed and unsigned are usually unexpected

To make the right hand side unsigned add the [`U` suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4380691/995714)

```
if(usart[RS485_PORT].tx_count == 0U)
```