# Data type U11 U1

Tags: c

I came across a program to configure alternate function for SPI GPIO port A.

```
GPIOA->CRL |= (11U<<20); // PA5 SCK AF output push pull

GPIOA->CRL |= (11U<<28); // PA7 MOSI AF output push pull
```

What does the 11U means? I know, it's something like setting the 20th bit to 11? is 11 the binary value for 3? how does the value 3 relates to PA5 SCK and 28 relates to PA7 MOSI?  Anyone can advise?

I had reading type date in C, and want to consult second option.

Can anyone kindly advise?

Comment: The integer 11 treated as an unsigned int. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant

Comment: In `11U` the `U` is an _unsigned suffix_ that makes `11` an `unsigned int`.

Comment: As others have said, the `U` suffix indicates that it is an unsigned int. The `<<` is the shift left operator. What decides whether it's PAS SCK or PA7 MOSI is the distance of the shift (20 bits vs. 28 bits).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of U suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380691/meaning-of-u-suffix)